# Is it possible to add an app to your wishlist in the desktop version of the App Store

Tags: macos, applications, mac-appstore

I love adding apps to my wishlist on the iPhone or iPad.

[image]

I would only find it normal that the same thing can be done with the Mac OS X version of the AppStore.

Obviously, this feature should be located under the little arrow of the price tag, right under the app's icon:

[image]

But it's not the case:

[image]

It seems that gifting an app from the Mac OS X version of the App Store isn't there either.

As we can see in the 3rd image, it isn't on the right-hand side either.

So, am I missing something, or is the desktop version of the App Store a diminished version of the iOS's?

Answer (score 1):

You're not missing anything, it is as you suggest. Make a [feature request](https://www.apple.com/feedback/) since the feature doesn't exist.